# Mistake in my implementation of merge sort?

Tags: python, mergesort

Here is my implementation of merge sort

```
    lis=list()
    lis=[9,0,5,1,8,3,7,2,6,4]

    def merge(lis,l,m,r):
        i=l
        j=m
        n1=m-1-l
        n2=r-m
        temp=list()
        while(i<=n1 and j<=n2):
            if(lis[i]<lis[j]):
                temp.append(lis[i])
                i+=1
            else:
                temp.append(lis[j])
                j+=1
        while(i<=n1):
            temp.append(lis[i])
            i+=1
        while(j<=n2):
            temp.append(lis[j])
            j+=1
        for k in range(len(temp)):
            lis[l+k]=temp[k]

    def mergesort(lis,l,r):
        if(l<r):
            m=(l+r)//2
            mergesort(lis,l,m)
            mergesort(lis,m+1,r)
            merge(lis,l,m,r)

    mergesort(lis,0,9)
    print(lis)
```

this is the output : [0, 5, 8, 3, 9, 1, 7, 2, 6, 4]
does sort for some recursions but hen bonks to death
is there a problem in math used please help

cannot figure out what is wrong with my code

Comment: yes did that still doesnt sort

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here did it

```
    '''
    n=int(input("Enter number of elements: "))
    lis=list()
    for i in range(n):
        lis.append(int(input("Enter element "+str(i+1)+": ")))
    '''
    lis=list()
    lis=[9,0,5,1,8,3,7,2,6,4]

    def merge(lis, l,m,r):
        i,j=l,m+1
        n1,n2=m,r
        srt=list()
        while(i<=n1 and j<=n2):
            if(lis[i]<lis[j]):
                srt.append(lis[i])
                i+=1
            else:
                srt.append(lis[j])
                j+=1
        while (i<=n1):
            srt.append(lis[i])
            i+=1
        while (j<=n1):
            srt.append(lis[j])
            j+=1
        m=l
        for k in srt:
            lis[m]=k
            m+=1

    def mergesort(lis,l,r):
        if(l<r):
            m=(l+r)//2
            mergesort(lis,l,m)
            mergesort(lis,m+1,r)
            merge(lis,l,m,r)

    mergesort(lis,0,9)
    print(lis)
```

Comment: Looks like you fixed your code. The only challenge was how you set i, j, n1, and n2 values. The first subarray has to be from l to m, and the second subarray has to be from m+1 to r. In other words, i to n1, and j to n2. Good you were able to fix it yourself. Kudos to you.

Answer (score 0):

Here it is, fixed and neat version -

```
def merge(lis, l, m, r):
    n1 = m - l + 1
    n2 = r- m

    L = [0] * (n1)
    R = [0] * (n2)

    for i in range(0 , n1):
        L[i] = lis[l + i]

    for j in range(0 , n2):
        R[j] = lis[m + 1 + j]

    i,j,k=0,0,l

    while i < n1 and j < n2 :
        if L[i] <= R[j]:
            lis[k] = L[i]
            i += 1
        else:
            lis[k] = R[j]
            j += 1
        k += 1

    while i < n1:
        lis[k] = L[i]
        i += 1
        k += 1

    while j < n2:
        lis[k] = R[j]
        j += 1
        k += 1

def mergesort(lis,l,r):
    if l < r:
        m = (l+(r-1))//2
        mergesort(lis, l, m)
        mergesort(lis, m+1, r)
        merge(lis, l, m, r)

lis=[9,0,5,1,8,3,7,2,6,4]
mergesort(lis,0,len(lis)-1)
print(lis)
```

Here is the most critical mistake you did.

`m=(l+r)//2` should be `m=(l+r)//2`

Comment: please do not paste geeksforgeeks' code, I want to know my own mistake